# Nestjs module as package and shared Repository

Tags: orm, architecture, nestjs, prisma, npm-package

I'm facing the following concept doubt:

I want to isolate a Nest module as an NPM Package, but this package when used have to save/load data into the database set in the main application. Now I am using Prisma

The package has your own prisma.schema that mush have merged with main prisma.schema (and with other packages).

I am not sure:

If the package must have a Prisma dependence
If the package can be injected with Prisma Instance from Main app
If the package can works without migrations, just with models (migration will be in the main app)
If for this scenario the Sequelize is better than Prisma (because the merged schema)

Thanks